# Set custom meta title for subsections

Tags: javascript, docusaurus

I have a Docusaurus site with a blog and two subsections (Knowledge Base, Topics): https://uplink.tech/blog/

All of them use the title defined in `docusaurus.config.js` (`module.exports = { title: 'Uplink Docs', ... }`) as the suffix of the "title" and "og:title" meta tags.

Obviously, I'd like to be able to use different suffixes there, e.g.:

- "Uplink Blog" for https://uplink.tech/blog/
- "Uplink Knowledge Base" for https://uplink.tech/knowledge-base/
- "Uplink Topics" for https://uplink.tech/topics/

I haven't found a way to do this yet...
Is this possible?